# iOS FBInterstitialAd issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, interstitial

I've implemented the Facebook Network SDK in my app, in form of an Interstitial Ad which appears when a UIViewController is loaded to screen. Everything worked ok until this morning, the controller loaded, the ad loaded, the user closed the ad and went on using the ap.
Now when the user closes the ad, the UIViewController is dismissed immediately. Nothing in the code was changed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    interstitialAd = [[FBInterstitialAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:@"xxxxxxx"];
    interstitialAd.delegate = self;
    [interstitialAd loadAd];
}

- (void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitial
{
    [interstitial showAdFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

This is my code. Any ideas ?

Comment: Same here… did the problem occurred in the Simulator or on a real device? On iOS 8 or 9?

Comment: The problem occurred on either Simulator and on a real device, on iOS 8 and 9. But the next day, without any changes, the problem was gone. Can't find an explanation really ...

Comment: Same here… I guess the server of Facebook sent shitty/unexpected values to the Framework which were processed badly. I investigated a little, the FAN SDK sent a dismiss three times instead of one when the interstitial was dismissed. (Seemingly from different function, usually related to the parsing of something ending…)